# JQuery return value from function in another function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a function in a function in jQuery Java Script and want to storage the value in a variable. Unfortunately, the variable is undefined. I think because I just return it from one of the functions, but I don't know how to pass through the other function.

```js
// Get value from range input
        const listenerInput = (inputID, labelID, buttonID) => {
            inputID.on("input", function () {
                labelID.text($(this).val() + " points");
                buttonID.prop("disabled", false);
                return $(this).val();
            });
        }


let npsRangeInput = listenerInput($("#npsInput"), $("#rangeV"), $("#qOneConfirmButton"));

 // Submit button
        $("#qOneConfirmButton").click(function () {
            console.log(npsRangeInput);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal__input">
                    <div class="input__container-two">
                        <input id="npsInput" type="range" name="npsInput" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">
                        <div class="modal__text" style="text-align:left;" id="rangeV">5 points</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
<div class="modal__button-wrap">
                    <button id="closeButton" class="modal__btn modal__btn--sec">Close</button>
                    <button id="qOneConfirmButton" disabled class="modal__btn modal__btn--main">Confirm</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Unsure how you expect an asynchronous event to somehow return its value to a variable. What you want to do is not possible. Set the variable directly inside the event listener function. Or just read the value inside the function

Comment: Instead of returning a value, take that value and set it into a variable that is accessible to the other function you need to use it in.

Comment: Okay thanks, and how can I make it adaptable for other variables if I have many different inputs?

Comment: Why do you need the variable? Just use `$("#npsInput").val()` whenever you need it.